# CSS full width minus margin left div, 20px same line right div

Tags: css, css-float, margin

I'm trying to make the first `div` child below use up `100%` of the available space minus `20px` and then use the second `div` child to use `20px` and be on the same line as the first child `div`.

```
<div style="width: 10%;">

<div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">Left side, should use up all space except margin!</div>

<div style="float: left; margin-left: -20px; width: 20px;">Should only use 20px no matter what.</div>

</div>
```

This should be able to be done with CSS level one (that means no `position` lame-outs) though I know I'm missing something. Also there will be `anchors` in both `div` elements that *must* use 100% of the available width so there is a trick here to get the `float` to behave a certain way...

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary for the divs to be floated?

Comment: There are several ways this can be and should be done. However, the most important question is, can your HTML structure change? If it can, it should.

Comment: Yes, the HTML can change changed. It is not necessary to include a `float` on one or either, I was just using it for testing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Solution #1

Make use of `overflow: hidden` (or overflow: auto) to fill the remaining horizontal space.

(**NB:** For this to work you need to place the element on the right hand side first in your markup)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rFzsS/2/)**

```
<div>
    <div class="div2">DIV 2</div>
    <div class="div1">DIV 1</div>   
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.div1 {
    background:yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.div2 {
    background:brown;
    float:right;
    width: 50px;
}
```

### Solution #2

You can do this with `box-sizing: border-box`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rFzsS/)**

```
<div>
    <div class="div1">DIV 1</div>
    <div class="div2">DIV 2</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.div1 {
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
.div2 {
    background:brown;
    float:left;
    width: 50px;
}
```

### Solution #3

Use css tables:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rFzsS/86/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">DIV 1</div>
    <div class="div2">DIV 2</div>
</div>

.container
{
    display:table;
}
.div1 {
    background:yellow;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
.div2 {
    background:brown;
    width: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
    word-break: break-word;
    min-width: 50px;
}
```

### Solution #4 (CSS3 required)

use `calc`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rFzsS/4/)**

On the first child set `width: calc(100% - 50px)`

On the second div set `width: 50px;`

```
.div1 {
    background:yellow;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    float: left;

}
.div2 {
    background:brown;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I can't use CSS level 2 position so that implies no CSS level 3. This is for a common layout and unfortunately CSS3 `calc` has very poor compatibility right now. Thank you for trying any way.

Comment: @John - I have just added 2 additional methods of doing this

Comment: Thanks...I can't brain right now, going to crash but I'll try it after I wake up and look at everyone else's. Thank you all.

Comment: Wow I just learned about calc... I always wanted this thing to exist, and now it does ! Also the easiest way to solve my problem

Comment: @ses . Thanks for spotting that. The problem was with words wider than 50px - where the right column would expand to the width of these long words. I updated the post adding  `word-break: break-word;
    min-width: 50px;` which fixes this issue

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the HTML structure a bit?

```
<div style="width: 10%;">
    <div style="display: block; width: 100%;">
        <div style="width: 20px; float: right;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using `display:table`.

```
<html>
<style>
body { padding:0; margin:0; display:table; width:100%; }
#content { display:table-row; }
#b1, #b2 { display:table-cell; }
#b1 { background-color:#eee; padding:2em; }
#b2 { width:20px; background-color:#bbb; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="b1">
<h1>Main content here</h1>
<p>Side bar on right is 20 px wide.</p>
</div>
<div id="b2">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```